# Socket IO returning GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1557980690629-0 404 0.758 ms - 1413

Tags: node.js, express, websocket, socket.io, ejs

I have some problem with socket.io, when i start my express app, it returning this error  `GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1557980690629-0 404 0.758 ms - 1413`

this is my app.js

```
let createError = require('http-errors');
let express = require('express');
let path = require('path');
let cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
let logger = require('morgan');
let bodyparser = require('body-parser');
let mongoose = require('mongoose');
let session = require('express-session')

let app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

io.on('connection', () =>{
    console.log('connected')
})

app.use(session({
    secret:'asd123',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie:{
        seccure: true
    }
}))
app.use((req,res,next)=>{
    app.locals.username = req.session.username || ""
    app.locals.userid = req.session.userid || ""
    next()
})

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/inventory', {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        keepAlive: true,
        keepAliveInitialDelay: 300000
    });
    const db = mongoose.connection;
    db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
    db.once('open', () => {
        req.db = mongoose.connection;
        next()
    });
})

const checkuser = (req,res,next)=>{
    if(req.session.username && req.session.userid && req.session.level){
        next()
    }else{
        res.redirect('/')
    }
}

let indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
let usersRouter = require('./routes/users');


// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyparser.json());
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use( (req, res, next) => {
    next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    // set locals, only providing error in development
    res.locals.message = err.message;
    res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

    // render the error page
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

the `console.log('connected')` isn't showing at console too

then i add this to my ejs file

```
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io();
</script>
```

i'm generating this using express-generator with ejs template also integrating with monggodb through mongoose driver, but i think the mongoose or monggodb doesn't have any problem with socket.io because they have different port

Comment: are you behind a proxy server something llike apache or nginx?

Comment: nope, i'm using laragon in localhost @JKK

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and it was solved this way

```
const cors = require('cors')
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const server = require('http').createServer(app);
const http = require("http");
app.use(cors());

const io = require("socket.io")(server, {
    allowEIO3: true,
    cors: {
        origin: true,
        credentials: true,
    },
});
```